# How to Create .appx package from C# Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, windows, build, appx

I have built a Windows Forms Application in C#, it has a sub process (.exe) built in c++. The Visual Studio Project I selected was Visual C# Windows Forms Application.

I have used the MakeAppx.exe in the Windows SDK, but after building and making a certification it gives me this error on install:

```
Windows cannot install package Microsoft.Sample.Application because this package requires a higher Windows version. The package requested Windows version 8.1 with AppModel version 0, while the current Windows version is 6.3 with AppModel version 0.
```

**Is there something wrong with my manifest file in the package?**

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Identity Name="Microsoft.SDKSamples.SampleApp"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x86"
            Publisher="CN=J Keith Becker, O=Keith Becker, L=Denver, S=Colorado, C=US"
            Version="1.0.0.0"
            ResourceId="en-us" 
  />

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>SampleApp</DisplayName>
    <Description>SampleApp</Description>
    <Logo>Logo.png</Logo>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Keith Becker</PublisherDisplayName>
  </Properties>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="SampleApp" StartPage="Default.html">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="SampleApp"
                      Logo="Logo.png"
                      SmallLogo="Logo.png"
                      Description="SampleApp"
                      BackgroundColor="#D1FFFC"
                      ForegroundText="light"
      >
        <DefaultTile WideLogo="Logo.png" />
        <SplashScreen Image="Logo.png" />
      </VisualElements>
    </Application>

  </Applications>

  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>8.1</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>10.0</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
</Package>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to install newer version of Windows SDK? Also, did you try to use the same commands with an empty, simple WPF app first?